# Как запустить событие для нескольких элементов без использования id и data-target?

Tags: javascript, html

При нажатии на тег i появляется или скрывается пароль в input. Можно ли сделать так чтобы при добавлении новых элементов input или же других, не пришлось менять или добавлять классы айди или атрибуты и чтобы как то без них работал код? Cпасибо.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>


    <input type="password" id="password-first"><i class="fa-solid fa-eye-slash" id="show-password-first" data-target="password-first"></i>
        <input type="password" id="password-second"><i class="fa-solid fa-eye-slash" id="show-password-second" data-target="password-second"></i>

        <script>
            let showPasswords = document.querySelectorAll('i.fa-eye-slash');
            showPasswords.forEach(showPassword => {
                showPassword.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
                    const targetId = showPassword.getAttribute("data-target");
                    const targetInput = document.getElementById(targetId);
                    
                    showPassword.classList.toggle("fa-eye")
                    const type = targetInput.getAttribute("type") === "password" ? "text" : "password";
                    targetInput.setAttribute("type", type);
                });
            });
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Что сейчас не так с кодом? Добавляете вы руками новые теги или скриптом?

Answer (score 0):

"Запустить событие для нескольких элементов" — не проблема, но для этого  желательно иметь понятный и близкий родительский элемент. А с учётом общей вложенности и того, что элементы должны влиять на соседа, то для дальнейшего удобства и упрощения работы нам не помешали бы родительские обёртки типа `<label>` и уже к ним применять псевдо-элементы с иконками, а не *все эти ваши* font-awesome со своими "тараканами":

Но поскольку имеем то, что вы нам предоставили, то:

1. создаём родительский div с единственным идентификатором на всю вёрстку;
2. убираем всё лишнее, а вместо него вводим минимально необходимый атрибут 'name'. Собственно он и не нужен для кода сейчас, но понадобится тогда, когда и если вы соберётесь эти input отправлять.

```js
passwords.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
  if(e.target.localName === 'i') {
    e.target.classList.toggle('fa-eye');
    const input = e.target.previousSibling;
    input.type = (input.type === 'password') ? 'text' : 'password';
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="passwords">
  <input type="password" name="pass_1"><i class="fa-solid fa-eye-slash"></i>
  <input type="password" name="pass_2"><i class="fa-solid fa-eye-slash"></i>
  <input type="password" name="pass_3"><i class="fa-solid fa-eye-slash"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: а что делать если например последний инпут находится в другом теге и ему придется добавить айди passwords?

Comment: @ᴋɪʀɪɢɪʀɪsan вы в моём коде видите один-единственный айдишник, без которого можно обойтись, заменив классом и по прежнему задаёте вопросы? Повторюсь,.. но, не зная смысла того, что вы творите, вам даже врач не поможет, что не так с моим предложением? можете даже хер нарисовать на лбЕ любому элементу моего когда, и он будет работать  _1 _2 _3 не являются необходимостью для работы кода, а возможно! понадобятся вам потом, когда вы начнёте понимать зачем вы эту дичь творите и какова её цель.

Answer (score -1):

если правильно понимаю у вас изначально есть некий набор инпутов и на них события слушаются нормально, но после добавляете еще некоторые инпуты и вот с ними уже проблемки в виде лени - чтоб их слышать приходится раскрашивать их всякими ид"ами и классами, верно же?

если так, можно создать форму `<form>` и все как минимум новые инпуты кидать в неё, а слушать уже саму форму целиком. или создать форму изначально.

на счет `что делать если инпут находится в другом теге` - есть атрибут `form`, как раз для связи с формой вопреки иерархии, но с js он работает не всегда так как от него ожидается(тут в сниппете у меня не хочет ивенты обрабатывать, хотя вроде должен :-/ )

```html
<form id='my_form' onchange='console.log(event)'>
<input type='checkbox' name='a'>
<input type='checkbox' name='b'>
<input type='checkbox' name='c'>
<input type='radio' name='d'>
<input type='radio' name='d'>
<input type='radio' name='d'>
</form>

<input form='my_form' type='checkbox' name='x'>
<input form='my_form' type='checkbox' name='y'>
<input form='my_form' type='checkbox' name='z'>
```